# can I pass a normal javascript object to typescript utility type Record<string, string>

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, typescript-utility

I need to set this property:

[image]

but this property was from external npm module written with typescript, launchParams requires a *Record<string,string>* type. my question is what is the exact way and the exact data to pass to set the value of launchParams ?

I tried to set launchParams with this:

`launchParams: {"homeurl" : "https://localhost"}`

but it seems it doens't work. launchParams is still undefined.

Comment: You used `lunchParams` instead of `launchParams`.

Comment: @vera. i actually update the property name to launchParams it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant to type 'launchParams:' and not 'lunchParams', then the problem looks like you are defining the type of launchParams and not assigning a value to it. Try

```
launchparams = {"homeurl" : "https://localhost"}
```

If that doesn't work you need to give more details, preferably a working example on Stackblitz that shows the problem.

Comment: Hi sir matt, I actually update the property name to launchParams but still not working, do you think I pass a wrong object? ty for the answer btw

Comment: You need a post an example that reproduces the issue so that people can work out the problem. There’s not enough information on your post to work out what’s going on